# mongodb not starting on mac os

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

mongod is not starting on my mac.

Here is the error I am getting when I run `mongod`

```
2019-02-05T18:30:15.744-0800 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=34864 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Dawits-MacBook-Pro.local
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.5
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-02-05T18:30:15.822-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-02-05T18:30:15.825-0800 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] An incomplete repair has been detected! This is likely because a repair operation unexpectedly failed before completing. MongoDB will not start up again without --repair.
2019-02-05T18:30:15.825-0800 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 50922 at src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp 86
2019-02-05T18:30:15.825-0800 F -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I did run mongod --repair and I get an error as follows. I am not sure how to fix this. Used to work fine a couple of weeks before.  this happend very recently

```
00 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-02-05T18:32:34.607-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-02-05T18:32:34.607-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2019-02-05T18:32:34.612-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase admin
2019-02-05T18:32:34.612-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection admin.system.version
2019-02-05T18:32:34.613-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-2-6265190839484826835. Not salvaging.
2019-02-05T18:32:34.639-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2019-02-05T18:32:34.639-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 250 megabytes of RAM
2019-02-05T18:32:34.654-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2019-02-05T18:32:34.655-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 250 megabytes of RAM
2019-02-05T18:32:34.691-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase local
2019-02-05T18:32:34.691-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection local.startup_log
2019-02-05T18:32:34.693-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-0-6265190839484826835. Not salvaging.
2019-02-05T18:32:34.718-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "local.startup_log" }
2019-02-05T18:32:34.718-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-02-05T18:32:34.738-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase loginapp
2019-02-05T18:32:34.739-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection loginapp.users
2019-02-05T18:32:34.740-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-0-7733536157857540484. Not salvaging.
2019-02-05T18:32:34.755-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: loginapp.users properties: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "loginapp.users" }
2019-02-05T18:32:34.756-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-02-05T18:32:34.770-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase test_1
2019-02-05T18:32:34.770-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection test_1.test_1
2019-02-05T18:32:34.774-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-0-3774245883137780326. Not salvaging.
2019-02-05T18:32:34.807-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: test_1.test_1 properties: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "test_1.test_1" }
2019-02-05T18:32:34.807-0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-02-05T18:32:34.823-0800 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2019-02-05T18:32:34.824-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-02-05T18:32:34.930-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Downgrading WiredTiger datafiles.
2019-02-05T18:32:35.116-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1549420355:116716][34873:0x7fffa63ce380], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 29/24576 to 30/256
2019-02-05T18:32:35.241-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1549420355:241902][34873:0x7fffa63ce380], txn-recover: Recovering log 29 through 30
2019-02-05T18:32:35.326-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1549420355:326013][34873:0x7fffa63ce380], txn-recover: Recovering log 30 through 30
2019-02-05T18:32:35.394-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1549420355:394299][34873:0x7fffa63ce380], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-02-05T18:32:35.617-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-02-05T18:32:35.618-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-02-05T18:32:35.618-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're receiving this error because the data files were originally written using a different version of Mongo than the version you're trying to run (apparently 4.0.5). If that's the case, you'll need to downgrade to the correct version - possibly 3.6.x or less. Follow [these procedures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/) to upgrade correctly.